# Unique storage for every function call inside React HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, memoization, high-order-component

I want to create a helper that generates some data and saves it in some variable and on the next execution, it should use the memoized value for calculation.

Basically it's a helper for the High Order wrapper. It means that the storage should be created for every HOC but it shouldn't be re-created on the next re-render.

Now it looks like: 
*pseudo code*

```
var storage; // I want to create this storage for every HOC only once.

function createDynamicStyles(theme, stylesCreator, status) {
// create a styles registry only once. This function can be re-called by the same HOC
// on each re-render so I want to use the memoized registry.
  if (!storage) { 
    storage = stylesCreator(theme);
   };

   return storage[status];
}

const styleCreator = theme => ({
  disabled: { color: theme.disabled },
  success: { color: theme.success }
})

const Component_1 = componentHOC((props) => {
  const { theme, status } = props;
  // I'd like to keep this helper call as simple as possible. It already has 3 arguments.
  const finalStyle = createDynamicStyles(theme, stylesCreator, status);

})(AwesomeComponent)

// these props can be changed during runtime
<Component_1 disabled={false} success={true} />
```

The functionality flow of this helper can be divided into 2 steps.

1) The first HOC call. It creates the styles based on the theme and saves them in the storage

2) Next Re-render of the HOC. It should fetch the previously created styles and return memoized value. This value should be unique for each HOC.

The problem is that the same helper can be used for other Components as well and it means that we can't use the same storage because it will be overwritten but the 'latest' HOC.

The possible ways how to solve it:

1) Create a class that will contain storage itself and creates a new Instance for each HOC.
To be honest, I'd like to avoid it because it looks too complicated for me in this case.

2) Create some Shared Registry and pass the UUID for every HOC. 
It'd be nice but I don't know how to automatically do it. I don't want to manually pass the UUID on each HOC. I'd like to have this functionality under the hood to keep HOC calls, lightweight.

I was thinking about the `new Map`, and saving the created styles as Key-Value pair but it simply doesn't work as we don't have the generated KEY reference in the HOC. So we can't use it as a key.

Is it possible to do such a thing in the case of plain functions only? 
Maybe I missed some other interesting variants.

Thanks for any help and suggestion.
Kind Regards.

Comment: Giving each instantiation of the HOC it's own instance of memoization construct is what it sounds like you're going for. I think you can achieve what you want with a functional component HOC using hooks (i.e. useMemo).

Comment: What Drew means is that you can do something like this: `const style = React.useMemo(
    () => createDynamicStyles(theme, stylesCreator),
    [theme]
  );
  const finalStyle = style[status];` If it keeps creating the style then you need to have a look at how theme is passed to this component.

Comment: Hi Drew Reese and HMR. Thanks for your suggestions. I tried to do it but it doesn't work as I want because in this case, we need to do separated 2 actions. Create the memoized style creator outside of the HOC (because it will be re-created on each re-render) and call it in the HOC directly. I want to keep code in 1 place. Another disadvantage of memo: Input Parameter expensive comparison. The **theme** object is complex so I need to use deepEqual comparison to detect when it was changes and update memo. Under the hood there are too many actions at my opinion.